# Splitting UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am making a photo collage app in iOS. The maximum number of photos is 12. After taking the photos I am arranging them in different frames in a grid fashion (like in PicCollage).

Now I want to add a feature by which the user can manipulate the edges of the frames. They can touch and make any particular imageview bigger or smaller one at a time (similar to the concept used in SplitPic). I am getting no idea about how to do this. I can manually keep a track of all the edges of the frames and then increment / decrement the x, y, width, height incrementally in touch move but is this the right approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached to each of your UIImageViews and do the necessary frame changes in it's methods. There's a ton of tutorials on the web for this.

You don't need to "manually keep track of the frames" - as long as they're displayed on screen (attached to some superview that is displayed), they will keep those values for you to inspect/modify.

Comment: Thanks I got an idea on how to implement this